# How to display time in Real-time in Virtual Pascal

Tags: time, pascal

I've been making a stock-keeping program for my school (In Virtual Pascal) and as part of that, I want to be able to display today's date along with the current time at the main menu of the program. Now, I've been able to display the correct date as that was pretty simple.

But when  I use this code for displaying Time, it only displays the time at which the program is compiled, and does not refresh to display the current time.

```
Procedure getTheTime;

VAR

      Hour, Minute, Second, Sec100   : WORD;

BEGIN

        GetTime( Hour, Minute, Second, Sec100 );
        TEXTCOLOR(lightgreen);
        whereY;
        whereX;
        WRITE;WRITE('                                                                       ');
        WRITE( Hour, ':', Minute, ':', Second, '.', Sec100);
END;
```

Basically, it displays this: 19:8:41.75
And I want the time to refresh as time goes by.

Any help would be appreciated.

The procedure where I call the getTheTime procedure.

```
Procedure mainMenu;

BEGIN
    REPEAT
            CLRSCR;
            getTheDate;
            getTheTime;
            TEXTCOLOR(15);
            GOTOXY(18,2);
            WRITELN('Welcome To RAK Academy''s School Shop');
            TEXTCOLOR(11);
            GOTOXY(18,3);
            WRITELN('------------------------------------');
            WRITELN;

            WRITE('A ':25);
            TEXTCOLOR(15);
            WRITELN(': Customers');
            WRITELN;
            TEXTCOLOR(11);

            WRITE('B ':25);
            TEXTCOLOR(15);
            WRITELN(': Products');
            WRITELN;
            TEXTCOLOR(11);

            WRITE('C ':25);
            TEXTCOLOR(15);
            WRITELN(': Orders');
            WRITELN;
            TEXTCOLOR(11);

            WRITE('X ':25);
            TEXTCOLOR(15);
            WRITELN(': Exit');
            WRITELN;
            GOTOXY(0,3);

            WRITE('Enter Choice: ':23);
            MenuChoice:=UPCASE(READKEY);
            sndPlaySound('F:\School\IB 1\HL subjects\Computer Science\Pascal programs\InternalAssessment\sound files\beep.wav', snd_Async or snd_NoDefault );
            TEXTCOLOR(11);;
            WRITELN(MenuChoice);
            TEXTCOLOR(15);
            DELAY(200);


            CASE MenuChoice OF

            'A' : CustomersMenu;
            'B' : ProductsMenu;
            'C' : OrdersMenu;
            'X' : BEGIN
                    sndPlaySound('F:\School\IB 1\HL subjects\Computer Science\Pascal programs\InternalAssessment\sound files\end.wav', snd_Async or snd_NoDefault );
                    WRITELN;
                    WRITELN('Program Is Shutting Down');
                    GOTOXY(25,15);
                    DELAY(750);
                    WRITE('.');
                    DELAY(750);
                    WRITE('.');
                    DELAY(750);
                    WRITE('.');
                    DELAY(750);
                  END

          ELSE
          BEGIN
             WRITELN;
             TEXTCOLOR(12);
             WRITELN('ERROR - Only Enter A-B Or X To Exit. Please Try Again.');
             TEXTCOLOR(11);
             READKEY;
          END;
          END;

    UNTIL menuChoice='X';

END;
```

Comment: Well, call it repeatly, e.g. once every n seconds. Typical ways to do this is from the event loop.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to do. Do you just want the program to keep updating the time on the screen? Does it need to act like a "clock" in which the digits change, or are you happy continually writing out a new time on a separate line? What time interval? Does the program need to do anything else while updating time, or is that all it does?

Comment: I would prefer it to act like a clock. The only other thing the program needs to do while updating the clock is wait for user input( Which is just a letter, A,B,C or X. Its a menu.) I assume then the clock would stop and my program would continue. I just want the clock to be there for the main screen. I can post more of the code if that would be helpful. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that waiting for that key is what I meant with that eventloop. You need to regularly abort that to update the clock. Maybe by using crt.keypressed and crt.readkey instead of system.read(ln).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the event loop. would you mind explaining it? I don't see it in Virtual Pascal's Index either. I changed the READLN to READKEY as you suggested @Marco van de Voort, and now the time refreshes with every keystroke as long as I'm still on the Main menu. So close, but I still would like it to refresh by itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the time at which the program is compiled, but the time at which the program is run.

The code between BEGIN-END runs once and then updates the time.
If you want the time to update you need to add a timer that updates the time when the OnTimer event triggers.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, to give you an idea how to do this:

```
var updatecounter : integer;
    mustexit      : Boolean;
updatecounter:=10; mustexit:=false;
repeat //eventloop start.
  if keypressed then
      begin
        c:=readkey;
        if c=#0 then 
          c2:=readkey;   // C=#0 is functionkey, read second value
        mustexit:=processkey(c,c2); // process whatever key is pressed
       end
    else
      begin
        sleep(10); // windows/winprocs unit? Don't know VP that well.
                   // pauses 10ms
        dec(updatecounter);
        if updatecounter=0 then // every 10*10ms update time
           begin
             updatetime; // update the time.
             updatecounter:=10;
           end;
      end;
until mustexit;
```

You can implement the various procedures and play with constants to get the responsivenes you want.